# Why do solar cells need to be square-shaped?

Tags: energy, solar-cells

There were circular solar cells 30 years ago. Why do we have square-shaped solar cells now? Why square?

Furthermore,

Why do monocrystalline solar cells have rounded/cropped edges?

[image]
Taken from: https://www.energysage.com/solar/101/monocrystalline-vs-polycrystalline-solar-panels/

Comment: I'd guess it's so the units can be tessellated easily i.e. you just make the units and choose the size, I'm sure hexagonal/triangular would work the same but this probably just adds unnecessary complexity in manufacturing

Comment: I'm surprised they were ever circular. I've not ever seen a circular solar cell. How big of a circle are we talking about? Wafer diameter circular? Because that's the only way I could see how.

Comment: It looks like the monocrystalline panels are trimmed from entire wafers cut from a circular boule. The standard wafer size about 30 years ago was 4"/100mm.

Comment: Indeed, single crystals are grown as round boules. Wafers are round and are generally processed as round units.

Comment: @Chemomechanics 30 cm diameter is of these Si ingots is a well established standard ([a reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwih0t_Ii9nwAhWIgf0HHXVADPIQFjAKegQICxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cup.lmu.de%2Fac%2Fkluefers%2Fhomepage%2Fpubl_pdf%2Fczochralski_engl.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0ynTl_5rWyJrJt1ss4UfNx)).  The next anticipated level is a diameter of 45 cm.

Comment: @Buttonwood Note that that report is for the IC industry, which has always sought larger wafers (even when very expensive) to ultimately decrease the cost per chip. However, it's not necessary or economical to use the largest wafers when you're trimming their edges and arranging them whole in a rectangular array. The burgeoning solar industry used hand-me-down equipment from IC fabs.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple perspectives to consider.  One is that the electric wiring of the individual elements into larger panels is easier if the elements are of rectangular shape:

[image]

(screen photo from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybvP8vjv1UY)).

An other reason is the that rectangular tiles cover a surface in a better, than circular ones.  For simplicity, let us compare square tiles of side length $a$ with circular ones of diameter $a$:

[image]

- The surface area of a square equates to $A(\mbox{square}) = a^2$.
- The surface of the circle with radius $r$ or diameter $a$ equates to

  $$A(\mbox{circle}) = \pi r^2 \leftrightarrow \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 \pi$$
- From the above illustration on may infer the difference between the two surfaces covered is $$A(\mbox{square}) - A(\mbox{circle})  = a^2 - \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 \pi = a^2 - \frac{\pi a^2} {4}.$$  Thus panels made of a circles leave about 22% of the area uncovered.

As mentioned in the comment by `@Aakash Lakshmanan`, other than square geometries equally allow a complete coverage of a floor.  Classically this boils down to the (crystallographic) [wallpaper groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group) *excluding* fivefold symmetry.

Comment: What about this: "Why do monocrystalline solar cells have rounded/cropped edges?"

Comment: @CemTuğanlı That could just be fragility purposes. Corners concentrate stresses and silicon wafers are already brittle.

Comment: @DKNguyen  However, the polycrystalline solar cell's corners are not cropped like what we see in monocrystalline solar cells. How could we explain this difference then?

Comment: Might have to do something with the stresses involved in the act of cutting the bar monocrystaline cells, whereas polycrystaline cells are cast. Although I would think the initial ingot was round to begin with and I don't know whether the bar is round, sliced up into thin wafers and then squared, or whether the bar is squared and then sliced up into thin wafers.

Comment: Same stress is not applied to polycrystalline cells? Why? @DKNguyen

Comment: Do you not know what casting is?

Comment: I do not know what casting is. @DKNguyen

Comment: Look it up. You can cast all sorts of things, including plastics, metals, and chocolate. You probably know what it is but just don't recognize the English word if it is not your first language.

Comment: @DKNguyen Okay, I know what it is :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your graph. Comparing a circle of diameter A and a square of sides A the circle always covers approximately 78.54% as much area as a square when A>0

Comment: upvoted the answer, but  you don't really need a graph here. You can only cover surface with rectangles and triangles, and rectangles are simply more practical for our rectangular cartesian brains.

Comment: @sleepy parallelograms and hexagons :P

Comment: @CemTuğanlı The tilted corners of the monocrystalline cells very likely are just the result the largest regular planar shape when cutting the large Si ingots (Czochralsky technique) like pancakes.  These are round, with tips at start and end, but are not of perfectly rotational symmetry.

Comment: @DKNguyen I thought of that, but hexagons can be made of triangles too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the solar cells having rounded and cropped edges, i believe it has to do with manufacturers that use all ready made silicon wafers in there processing. These wafers might be grown with respect to a certain plane and some cutting of the coroners might perhaps reduce internal stress and make it easier to cut the wafer.

That is my guess, someone working in the industry might have better insight to this.